# XSLT returns atomic values

Tags: xml, xslt

As an example, I have following XML:

```
<Root>
  <A>
    <H>header1</H>
    <B>
        <C>2</C>
    </B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <H>header2</H>
    <B>
        <C>3</C>
    </B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <H>header3</H>
  </A>
  <A>
    <H>header4</H>
  </A>
</Root>
```

I want a transformation to get H elements of only A elemenets that have B child. I wrote following XSLT:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl ="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A[B]"> 
    <Row>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="H"/>
        </Result>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is (using Notepad++'s XML Tools plug-in):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Row><Result>header1</Result></Row>
  <Row><Result>header2</Result></Row>

    header3


    header4

</Root>
```

Why are there just plain strings "header3" and "header4"? I expected following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Row><Result>header1</Result></Row>
  <Row><Result>header2</Result></Row>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

you are applying templates to the `Root` element. You don't have a template matching `Root`, so it is processed by the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule). These templates process `Root` and all its descendants (except `A[B]`, for which you do have a template) recursively and copy all text nodes to the output.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" 
xmlns:xsl ="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="A[B]"/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A"> 
    <Row>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="H"/>
        </Result>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```